# Compile HTML in AngularJS for Excel Export

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following function to export an HTML table that is generated with angularJS to Excel.
What I am missing at the moment is to get the compiled HTML, as I currently get just the InnerHTML code which is not yet compiled and thus the data is not returned at all.

```
exportAsExcel(tableId: string, fileName: string, linkElement: any) {

        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64 = function (s) {
                return window.btoa(decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(s)));
            },

            format = function (s, c) {
                return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                    return c[p];
                });
            };

        this.common.$timeout(() => {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
            var ctx = {
                worksheet: fileName,
                table: table.innerHTML
            };

            // if browser is IE then save the file as blob, tested on IE10 and IE11
            var browser = window.navigator.appVersion;
            if ((browser.indexOf('Trident') !== -1 && browser.indexOf('rv:11') !== -1) ||
                (browser.indexOf('MSIE 10') !== -1)) {
                var builder = new MSBlobBuilder();
                builder.append(uri + format(template, ctx));
                var blob = builder.getBlob('data:application / vnd.ms - excel'); //application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName + '.xls');
            } else {
                var element = document.getElementById(linkElement);
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
                a.target = '_blank';
                a.setAttribute('download', fileName + '.xls');
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();

            }
            toastr.success("We've created an Excel report for you and you should get it as a download in your browser.", "Awesome!");
        }, 100); 

    }
```

Any idea what to enhance/change in order to get the table.innerHTML compiled?

Thanks a ton for any hint you might have!

Comment: Use angular $compile()....see docs. Sounds like you are calling this too early in the page load process though

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your hint. Where / when would you call it? Because of that thought initially, I did a timeout. But that didn't really help.